# How to do user login correctly with nodejs and express

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I am very new to web development, and have been using Google as a guide.

If I put a wrong login that does not match what I have in my database, the website just gets stuck and keeps trying to “load”. I also am confused on how to do token-based authentication for login and would love some more guidance on that, the guide I am following talks about database encryption and OAuth 2.0 with Google.

If the user logs in with a username and password that is not correct, I just want it to give an error and reload back to login.ejs.

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue might be you are not returning anything when `foundUser` is null or if the password doesn’t match.

If there is any error you can redirect it to the `/login` route with query param (err) which can be read by the client using JS at page load. If there is a nonempty query param `err` then read it and show it in some popup.

`res.redirect("/login?err=The username does not exist");`

```
//connect to mongodb
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/userDB", {
    useNewUrlParser: true
});

const userSchema = {
    username: String,
    password: String
};

const User = new mongoose.model("User", userSchema);

app.get("/", function(req, res) {
    res.render("home"); //render home.ejs
});

app.get("/login", function(req, res) {
    res.render("login"); //render login.ejs
});

app.post("/login", function(req, res) {
    const username = req.body.username;
    const password = req.body.password;

    try {
        User.findOne({
            username: username
        }, function(err, foundUser) {
            if (err || !foundUser) {
                return res.redirect("/login?err=The username does not exist");
            }
            if (foundUser.password !== password) {
                // you can use  bcryptjs for hashing and comparing hashed values.

                return res.redirect("/login?err=The username or password is invalid");
            }
            res.redirect("/counter");
        });
    } catch (error) {
       res.redirect("/login?err=something went wrong!");
    }
});
```

You can read more about handling authentication in nodeJS [here](https://scotch.io/tutorials/authenticate-a-node-es6-api-with-json-web-tokens). also check [passportjs](http://www.passportjs.org/)

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I did not realize the power of try and catch. When I did that, and I put in a "wrong login", my localhost crashes and says unable to connect. I took out the ?err= messages you wrote as well to test. Your code makes sense to me though. Is bycryptjs token authentication? I have javascript and jquery in my partials footer.ejs

Comment: @sukiyo I have updated my answer. I missed the return statement.

Comment: Thank you so much!!!!!! I did not know about return statements in app.js as well! How come in your catch you did not write a return statement? And thank you for the links! I will look!

Comment: @sukiyo  bcrypt is a password hashing function and bycryptjs is a nodejs module which provides the same. - https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcryptjs

Comment: @sukiyo you can write a return statement in catch too but it is not required as there are no other statements to execute further i.e it reached end of the method.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. Oh I did not realize that about return statements, I am learning as I go ^^.